# Mapear caminho de outro Projeto

Tags: asp, caminho-relativo

Tenho uma solução WEB `ASP`, e tenho 4 projetos na solução. Tenho que mapear o caminho de uma pasta (**Imagens**) que esta em um projeto chamado `ADMIN`. E do meu projeto WEB tenho que salvar as imagens dentro desta mesma pasta.

meu codigo do diretorio esta assim...

```
diretorio = Server.MapPath("~/Imagens/"); // mas ele da erro diz que o caminho virtual nao pode ser encontrado...
```

Ai peguei e coloquei todo o caminho assim...

```
diretorio = Server.MapPath("~/siteWEB/siteADMIN/Imagens/"); // que seria o caminho todo mas ele da o mesmo erro, que o caminho nao pode ser encontrado.
```

Como salvar imagens em projetos diferentes?

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt. Só para lhe ajudar a se acostumar com nossa filosofia, que é diferente de um fórum, dê uma olhada em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior, especialmente o 3o. item. Se ainda não leu, seria bom dar uma olhada em [about], você ganha uma medalha. Você pode usar o [edit] para deixar sua pergunta com o jeito de uma pergunta direta e limpa. Aos poucos você vai acostumando.

Answer (score 1):

É importante lembrar que o caminho deve ser o diretório fisico no servidor como por exemplo:

```
Server.MapPath("C:\Inetpub\wwroot\SeuProjeto\Imagens")
```

Também lembrando que ASP 3.0 não aceita `;` no final das linhas/comandos.

Comment: esta errada a resposta, o Server.MapPath é justamente para traduzir o caminho relativo (../imagens) em c:\inetpub\etc

Answer (score 0):

Essa pasta imagens esta em qual localização perante o seu código asp ?

ex:

```
root/
    /arquivo.asp
    /Imagens/
```

se for assim, basta

```
diretorio = Server.MapPath("Imagens/")
```

agora se estivesse assim:

```
root/
    /etc/
    /etc/arquivo.asp
    /imagens/

diretorio = Server.MapPath("../Imagens/")
```

Não me recordo mais, mas creio que ASP não tem como voltar todas as pastas, tente:

```
diretorio = Server.MapPath("\Imagens")
```